# How to copy files while keeping directory structure?

Tags: 12.10, directory

This is for a java project, but the same concept can be applied more generally:

Basically, I have a projects with all `*.java` files located in some sub directory of `src`. Now I want to grab all directories with the name test in that directory tree and move them into a new directory called `tests`, e.g.:

```
src->com->a1
          -> A.java
          -> B.java
          -> test
              -> test1.java
              -> test2.java
```

to

```
src->com->a1
          -> A.java
          -> B.java
tests->com->a1->test
                -> test1.java
                -> test2.java
```

How would I best do that?

Comment: Does it need to create the parent directories `tests/com` and `tests/com/a1` for you?

Comment: not tests/ but the others, yes. That's why said it has to keep directory structure - that is, it has to create them if they aren't already there

Comment: are there other files, or just the *.java ones?

Comment: is there some reason that you can't just drag and drop in the file browser?

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Other than that that won't do what I asked? No.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a shell script for this task. I'll give it a try and comment the lines.

The first line here is just a variable where you put the absolute directory of your `src` tree.

```
SRCDIR=/dir/where/src/lives
```

The next line executes `find`. The command will put every directory path with the name `test` into the variable `TESTDIRS`.

```
TESTDIRS=$(find $SRCDIR -type d -name test)
```

Now you iterate over all found `test` directories

```
for dir in $TESTDIRS; do
```

This takes the actual path and removes everything including `src`. So you get the structure for creating the new path.

```
  NEWDIR=${dir##*/src}
```

Now create the new directories.

```
  mkdir -p tests/$NEWDIR
```

Move the old `test` directory to the newly created place.

```
  mv $dir tests/$NEWDIR
```

end the iteration

```
done
```

As far as I understand you this should what you want. But please test it first. There might be some caveats and running the script as is might lead to data loss.

Answer (score 1):

I use one these commands to copy all my jpg files and skip all the db, raw etc files. Either one should work for your needs.

Using `rsync`:

```
 rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.jps' --exclude '*'  source/ target/
```

Or `find` with `exec`:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the meanings of move `mv` and copy `cp` are distinct and well defined for terminal usage. `mv` means that the files will no longer exist in the old location, while `cp` means that a duplicate is made in the new location.

Simple solution (notice that I use `mv`, but you may want to use `cp` first and then remove the old files once the copying is what you want):

```
cp src/com/a1/test/test*.java tests/com/a1/test/
```

More elegant solution (this one moves the files, not copies):

```
cd src/com/
find . -iname "test*.java" -type d -exec mv {} ../../tests/com/ \;
```

If the second solution doesn't work for your specific test case, we can iterate...

Comment: This doesn't do what I asked. I need to move ALL test folders from ALL sub folders to tests, keeping the directory structure.

Comment: In order to find all the files in "test" folders, run this command: `find . -type d -name "test" -exec ls -l {} \;` Use the `type -d` flag after the dot to search only directories and the `type -f` flag for files. You can figure out how to move the files based on the above answer.